# Renamed folders do not have their new names until I hit F5, how do I get auto-refresh back?

Tags: windows-10

Rename a folder from XYZ to ABC. The new name is not visible in Explorer. Double click (or press enter) on the folder. Windows will say "Folder cannot be found".

It appears that Explorer is not aware that the folder was not renamed. I have seen some fixes for this on the internet but none for Windows 10.

Comment: I have always solved this by rebooting.  Is thi happening on just one folderm. If that doesnt work, try removing shell extensions and desktop.ini files.

Comment: Try suggestion by Truth101 on this page...http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/147221-Desktop-and-Windows-Explorer-will-not-auto-refresh-must-hit-F5

Comment: You may want to try running a command prompt and executing 'sfc /scannow'. It might take a bit however it should fix most disk problems